# how to improve performance in apex trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I am new to apex. I need to write a trigger on the Account object.

Whenever account is added or updated, I will check if the Description field is not empty or was changed. The account description field will contain the child account names. ```

Comment: Google for how to use maps to avoid a query inside a loop. But using the default parent reference on Account or adding your own lookup would make for a more robust and scalable system than the comma separated list of names.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [Aggregate-Query-Update Pattern](https://sfdcfox.blogspot.com/2017/03/the-aggregate-query-update-pattern.html). That is, you need to first get all the child names you're interested in finding, grabbing those children, then performing any updates you need (in this, case, creating child accounts). That would approximately look like:

```
trigger OnAccountChangeTrigger on Account(after insert,after update) {
    Map<Id, Set<String>> oldChildNamesByParentId = new Map<Id, Set<String>>();
    Map<Id, Set<String>> newChildNamesByParentId = new Map<Id, Set<String>>();
    Map<String, Account> postChildAccountsByName = new Map<String, Account>();
    Map<String, Account> preChildAccountsByName = new Map<String, Account>();
    Set<String> allChildNames = new Set<String>();
    Account[] childAccountsToUpsert = new Account[0];

    // Helper method //
    void populateChildDataMaps(Account[] records, Map<Id, Set<String>> childNamesByParentId, Set<String> allChildNames) {
        for(Account record: records) {
            Set<String> childNames = new Set<String>();
            if(record.Description != null) {
                childNames.addAll(record.Description.split(','))
            }
            childNamesByParentId.put(record.Id, childNames);
            allChildNames.addAll(childNames);
        }
    }

    // Aggregate //
    populateChildDataMaps(Trigger.new, newChildNamesByParentId, allChildNames);
    if(Trigger.isUpdate) {
        populateChildDataMaps(Trigger.old, oldChildNamesByParentId, allChildNames);
    }
    for(String childName: allChildNames) {
        preChildAccountsByName.put(childName, new Account(Name=childName, ParentId=null));
        postChildAccountsByName.put(childName, new Account(Name=childName, ParentId=null));
    }

    // Query //
    for(Account record: [SELECT Name, ParentId FROM Account WHERE Name = :allChildNames]) {
        preChildAccountsByName.put(record.Name, record.clone(true, false, false));
        postChildAccountsByName.put(record.Name, record.clone(true, false, false));
    }
    // Update //
    if(Trigger.isUpdate) {
        for(Account record: Trigger.old) {
            for(String oldChildName: oldChildNamesByParentId.get(record.Id)) {
                postChildAccountsByName.get(oldChildName).ParentId = null;
            }
        }
    }
    for(Account record: Trigger.new) {
        for(String newChildName: newChildNamesByParentId.get(record.Id)) {
            postChildAccountsByName.get(newChildName).ParentId = record.Id;
        }
    }
    // Only perform DML on records that were modified
    for(String childName: postChildAccountsByName.keySet()) {
        if(preChildAccountsByName.get(childName) != postChildAccountsByName.get(childName)) {
            childAccountsToUpsert.add(postChildAccountsByName.get(childName));
        }
    }
    childAccountsToUpsert.sort();
    Database.upsert(childAccountsToUpsert, Account.Id);
}
```

Some additional optimization should be possible from here, but this is the basic design of what you're looking for.

Comment: any particular reason why did you use `record.clone(true, false, false)` before adding it to the map?

Comment: @NagendraSingh Because we're storing objects in those maps, they need to be distinct objects in memory, or an update to one map's accounts would update both, and we wouldn't see any changes correctly. I clone twice just to make sure I have the same fields populated in each copy.